# Connecting Titan To Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, titan

I am trying to connect titan to solr. The properties file I am using is `titan-cassandra-solr.properties` :

```
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.solr.mode=cloud
index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=localhost:2181
```

I have configured my titan core to be:

**name:** `titan`
**instance:** `/opt/solr-titan/titan`
**data:** `/opt/solr-titan/data`

inside `/opt/solr-titan/titan` I have a `conf` directory which contains all the files I copied from `titandb/conf/solr`.

When I use `gremlin.sh` and try:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-solr.properties")
==>standardtitangraph[cassandrathrift:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V()
==>v[4328]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has("MY_ID", "www.mindmaps.com/action-movie")
==>v[4328]
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has("MY_ID", "action-movie")
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has("MY_ID", "www.mindmaps.com/action-movie")
==>v[4328]
```

it all seems to be working but when I run:

```
TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-solr.properties");
```

I get the following exception:

```
6:02:51,191  INFO ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16:02:51,212  WARN ClientCnxn:1102 - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get titan to talk to solr by doing the following:

**Change my solr core.** I simple ran solr by using `solr start -e schemaless` then I changed `titan-cassandra-solr.properties` to be:

```
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.solr.mode=http 
index.search.solr.zookeeper-url=http://localhost:8983/solr
```

**Clean Titan.** Run `titan.sh stop` followed by `titan.sh clean`

After this I was able to connect to Titan through my java code. I still need do more to get this working cloud mode but for now this seems to work.

Comment: Hi , I have a graph in cassandra which I created and stored using java. I want to index the same graph present in cassandra to solr how can I do so using java? I want to do so by getting data from cassandra and index in solr.